# Same Object got Exception on Update but not on Insert

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework

I do build an object with the information, that after it will run on a background Thread to do what must be done to the DB.

The same object is build allways the same way, so it will see if exist all rdy inside the DB if it does it will update it if not insert a new one.

The insert did work at 100% but when I was trying the Update got an error

> Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a
>   separate thread.
>
> at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Text() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   DocumentForm.RunOnBackGroundDB()

This is the Code:

How I build the Object

```
this._IdentifierToCheck = this.textBoxIdentifier.Text;
this._CodBarToCheck = this.textBoxCodBar.Text;
this._prodToShow = new ProdToShow();
this._prodToShow.Ref = this.textBoxRef.Text;
this._prodToShow.Descr = this.textBoxDescr.Text;
this._prodToShow.PreviousQtd = float.Parse(this.textBoxPrevQtd.Text);
this._prodToShow.Qtd = float.Parse(this.textBoxNewQtd.Text);
this._prodToShow.Price = float.Parse(this.textBoxPrice.Text);
this._prodToShow.UnitType = this._unitList[this.comboBoxUnits.SelectedIndex].id;
this._prodToShow.UnitValue = float.Parse(this._unitList[this.comboBoxUnits.SelectedIndex].unit);
if (String.Equals(this.btnNewProdOpType.Text, "+"))
{
    this._prodToShow.AddEquals = true;
}
else
{
    this._prodToShow.AddEquals = false;
}
this._workerThread.Start();
```

The code when is New or must be updated

```
if (prodExistOnDoc)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        float total = 0;
        if (this._prodToShow.AddEquals)
        {
            total = this._prodToShow.PreviousQtd + this._prodToShow.Qtd;
        }
        else
        {
            total = this._prodToShow.Qtd;
        }
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Pda_Lancamentos_lin Cod_Art = @codArt, Descricao = @descr, Qtd = @Qtd, Preço = @price, id_uni = @unitID, unidade = @unit "
            + "WHERE Tipo = @type AND Identificador = @iden AND Cod_Barras = @codBar";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", this._tempDocInfo.Type);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iden", this._IdentifierToCheck);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codBar", this._CodBarToCheck);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codArt", this._prodToShow.Ref);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr", this._prodToShow.Descr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qtd", total);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", this._prodToShow.Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitID", this._prodToShow.UnitType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", this._prodToShow.UnitValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
// New prod to the document
else
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pda_Lancamentos_Lin (Tipo, Identificador, Cod_Barras, Cod_Art, Descricao, Qtd, Preço, id_uni, unidade) VALUES " +
            "(@type, @iden, @codBar, @codArt, @descr, @Qtd, @price, @unitID, @unit)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", this._tempDocInfo.Type);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iden", this._IdentifierToCheck);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codBar", this._CodBarToCheck);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codArt", this._prodToShow.Ref);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr", this._prodToShow.Descr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qtd", this._prodToShow.Qtd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", this._prodToShow.Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitID", this._prodToShow.UnitType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", this._prodToShow.UnitValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

From what I did understood of the Exception is saying that I can't have access to a Forms.Control but I'm not accessing to anything of that type, on the update the only difference is I must calculate the qtd if need to Add to the previous one, and I do pass everything what I need to the background thread into a variable so I don't access the stuff from the UI Thread to prevent this error

Rly don't understand the -1 all rdy ... since the same object works on the insert, the only difference is that I'm doing some calculation when its an update and the variable is created on the background thread ...

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the dam 'set' after the table name -.- time to rest a little